# timestamp() do not take function parameter as input?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am using sql in postgresql

```
cast(col as timestamp($1))
```

It gives me error around parameter

The sql works when I give the number directly:

```
cast(col as timestamp(1))
```

So timestamp do not take function parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The [precision modifier of the `timestamp` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) is part of the type *name* and cannot be parameterized in plain SQL. That's not a function, even though the syntax with parentheses looks the same.

You would need dynamic SQL for that. In a PL/pgSQL function build the statement as string and run it with `EXECUTE`. Something like:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT col::timestamp(' || $1 || ')'
INTO my_var;
```

`$1` being type `integer`. Not a string type like `text`, or you have a possible SQL injection hole.